# A nice Nesbitt inequality from a strange inequality

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

Given $a,\,b,\,c> 0$$,$ prove that$:$
$$\frac{a}{b+ c}+ \frac{b}{c+ a}+ \frac{c}{a+ b}+ \frac{63}{5}\left [ \frac{2\,c^{\,2}}{(\,a+ b\,)^{\,2}}- \frac{c}{a+ b} \right ]\geqq 0$$
See$:$ $\lceil$ https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h354642p1923888 $\rfloor$

The only way I tried is Buffalo Way but the coefficient of$:$ $\text{coef}[\,c^{\,4}\,],\,\text{coef}[\,c^{\,3}\,],\,\text{coef}[\,c^{\,2}\,],\,\text{coef}[\,c\,],\,\text{coef}[\,c^{\,0}\,]$ aren$'$t same non$-$negative$,$ maybe I$'$m wrong because the equality occurs with $a= b$$.$ So I ask$,$ hope to see the best way$!$ Good luck everybody$!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac{x}{2}$.

Thus, by C-S and AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{2c^2}{(a+b)^2}-\frac{c}{a+b}\right)=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}+\frac{b^2}{ab+bc}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\geq\frac{(a+b)^2}{2ab+c(a+b)}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{2ab}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{c}{a+b}}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{63}{5}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\geq0$$ or $$63x^3+5x^2-58x+20\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$f\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{63}{5}\left[\frac{2c^2}{(a+b\, )^2}-\frac{c}{a+b}\right]\ge 0$$

Let $t=\dfrac{a+b}2>0$. We hope that $f(a,b,c)\ge f(t;t;c)$. Indeed,

$$f(a,b,c)-f\left(t,t,c\right)=\frac{\left(a-b\right)^2\left(a+b+c\right)}{\left(a+c\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(a+b+2c\right)}\ge 0$$

So we only prove $f(t,t,c)\ge0$

Or $$63c^3+5c^2t-58ct^2+20t^3\ge 0$$

Comment: Why do you only prove in $a=b$?

Comment: And your solution is as same as @MichaelRozenberg!

Comment: That's totally wrong! Such as$a= 2\,a\,/\,3+ b\,/\,3,\,b= 2\,b\,/\,3+ a\,/\,3\,\therefore\,\frac{a+ b}{2}= \frac{2\,a\,/\,3+ b\,/\,3+ 2\,b\,/\,3+ a\,/\,3}{2}$, but you can fix it or dele it if better! Thanks for your trying a real real lot!

Comment: I'm not good at explaining so i only can show you some example. Example: we need to prove $f(a,b,c)\ge 0$

we proved that: $f(a,b,c)\ge f(t;t;c)$ then we only prove $f(t;t;c)\ge 0$ which is $a=b$

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @WordShallow, there is a big problem here, for $f(\,a,\,b,\,c\,)$, $a$ and $b$ are in the same role (symmetry), if that $f(\,t,\,t,\,c\,)$, $a$ and $b$ are also in the same role! You say we only prove with $a= b$, if that, why can't we assume $f(\,a,\,a,\,c\,)\geqq 0$ before, I think HaiDangel29 is right, his way is $f(\,t,\,t,\,c\,)= g(\,a,\,b,\,c\,)\geqq g(\,t,\,t,\,c\,)\geqq\,...\,\geqq 0$. Your way is incorrected!,

Comment: $a= 2\,a\,/\,3+ b\,/\,3,\,b= 2\,b\,/\,3+ a\,/\,3\,\therefore\,\frac{a+ b}{2}= \frac{2\,a\,/\,3+ b\,/\,3+ 2\,b\,/\,3+ a\,/\,3}{2}$. I think if you prove with $a= b$, that's true with $a= b$ and only with $a= b$, because with $a= b$ then $t= a= b$. It's the original inequality, and $a= b$ is only the inequality condition! No sure for your inequality, because $f(\,a,\,b,\,c\,)\geqq 0\,\therefore\,f(\,t,\,t,\,c\,)\geqq 0$, and your prove is totally wrong, if $a= b$ then $f(\,a,\,b,\,c\,)\geqq 0\,\because\,f(\,t,\,t,\,c\,)\geqq 0$. (nonsense!) Hope you edit it again!